# Spring Boot не запускается после подключения JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, configuration

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the connection string near ';serverTimezone=UTC'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте исправить настройку в [`application.properties`](https://github.com/akasyuka/Spring/blob/e5e5b96fbd1dff7a580edd9571e30a6ec97008c5/src/main/resources/application.properties), заменив `&amp;` на обычный `&`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3307/db_tea?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```